# AWS Aurora (PostgreSQL) queries with client address = null

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

We are running a Django application with a AWS Aurora (PostgreSQL) database and are debugging some of our queries.

When we look at the running queries using following statement:

```
select
    pid,
    usename,
    datname,
    application_name,
    client_addr,
    query,
    now() - query_start
from
    pg_stat_activity
where
    usename <> 'rdsadmin';
```

We see a lot of duplicate queries where `client_addr = <null>`. The application_name and user however are the same (= our Django app). Most queries from our Django app include the correct `client_addr`.

Can someone explain why we see these duplicate queries that contain no `client_addr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the official [document](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#:%7E:text=to%20this%20backend-,client_addr,-inet):

`IP address of the client connected to this backend. If this field is null, it indicates either that the client is connected via a Unix socket on the server machine or that this is an internal process such as autovacuum.`